# Manipulation DOM with Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-extension

in my Chrome Extension with a popup I want to open a certain number of tabs and after loading I want manipulate the DOM with variables.

I can open the tabs but I cannot find a way to send my data to tab.

Maybe the better way is to open the Url with the POST method and send the data directly?

popup.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    "use strict";
    $('button').on('click', function () {
        chrome.tabs.create({ windowId: window.id, url: "http://www.url1.com" }
        // manipulate the dom/form data with 2 variables, which are given
        // var1 = xxx and var2 = yyy
        chrome.tabs.create({ windowId: window.id, url: "http://www.url2.com" }
        // manipulate the dom/form data with 2 variables, which are given
        // var3 = 123 and var4 = 678

    });
});
```

Comment: You should probably be using a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).

Answer (score 0):

Please use postMessage CHROME API for send or receive data between any following scripts.

- background.js
- content_script.js
- popup.js

Please refer following doc for details in details.

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging